# IllegalArgumentException: No interpolator found for float during implementing Substance LAF

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, substance

I have tried to implement Substance LAF. I have also downloaded Trident library. Application will normally start (with LAF chosen from package structure) but when I try to used menus in `JMenuBar` I get exception below.

I have found very similar problem but it is definitely something different – [Flamingo ribbon: Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No interpolator found for java.lang.Float:java.lang.Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26054610/flamingo-ribbon-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-interpolator-found-for-j).

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:     No interpolator found for 
java.lang.Float:java.lang.Float 
 at org.pushingpixels.trident.TimelinePropertyBuilder.getFieldInfo    (TimelinePropertyBuilder.ja 
 va:257) 
 at org.pushingpixels.trident.Timeline.addPropertyToInterpolate    (Timeline.java:353) 
 at org.pushingpixels.trident.Timeline.addPropertyToInterpolate    (Timeline.java:363) 
 at     org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.animation.StateTransitionTracker.onModelStat    eChanged 
 (StateTransitionTracker.java:394) 
 at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.ui.SubstanceMenuUI$1.mouseEntered        (SubstanceMenuUI.ja 
 va:155) 
 at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseEntered(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) 
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEnterExit(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.trackMouseEnterExit(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) 
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
 at     java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege    (Unknown Sou 
 rce) 
 at     java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege    (Unknown Sou 
 rce) 
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) 
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
 at     java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege    (Unknown Sou 
 rce) 
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) 
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: *"Any ideas?"* Use a different PLAF. Do you want to make your question more specific?

Comment: Crossposted: http://www.coderanch.com/t/665093/GUI/java/IllegalArgumentException-interpolator-float-implementing-Substance#3097418

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to this, after some good hours. The error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No interpolator found for java.lang.Float:java.lang.Float

has nothing to do with the code in the `TimelinePropertyBuilder` class. **It is instead missing the `trident-plugin.properties` file in the `META-INF` of the respective top-level library.** There exactly are being defined the Interpolator classes sources.

So instead of looking for it, here is the so much needed `trident-plugin.properties`:

```
UIToolkitHandler=org.pushingpixels.trident.swing.SwingToolkitHandler
PropertyInterpolatorSource=org.pushingpixels.trident.swing.AWTPropertyInterpolators

UIToolkitHandler=org.pushingpixels.trident.swt.SWTToolkitHandler
PropertyInterpolatorSource=org.pushingpixels.trident.swt.SWTPropertyInterpolators

UIToolkitHandler=org.pushingpixels.trident.android.AndroidToolkitHandler
PropertyInterpolatorSource=org.pushingpixels.trident.android.AndroidPropertyInterpolators

PropertyInterpolatorSource=org.pushingpixels.trident.interpolator.CorePropertyInterpolators
```

This should sort it out.